# Is it safe to dispose HttpConfiguration?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin, httpconfiguration

My [CA2000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2000?view=vs-2019) analyzer ("Dispose objects before losing scope") tells me to dispose of the `HttpConfiguration` instance once I've done customizing OWin's `IAppBuilder`.

I tried to do just that and everything works suspiciosly fine. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh835519(v%3Dvs.118)) doesn't tell anything about should I or should I not dispose `HttpConfiguration`, as it does about, say, Tasks ("dont bother disposing Task instances").

Since I don't want to leave an instance undisposed, as much as I don't want to find my web server crashed some day, what should I do?

Edit, part of my code:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    EnableCookieAuth(appBuilder);
    UseWebApi(appBuilder);
}

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Reliability", "CA2000:Dispose objects before losing scope", Justification = "Handled by ")]
private static void UseWebApi(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    appBuilder.Use<ControlMiddleware>();

    using HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    appBuilder.UseNinjectWebApi(config);
    config.EnsureInitialized();
}
```

Comment: `CA2000` is often wrong because C# doesn't provide a way to declare or specify object ownership transfer (unlike Rust), it also doesn't know about objects which implement `IDisposable` but should not normally be disposed or have special rules for disposing them (like `HttpClient`).

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Dai yeah I know that, that's why I'm asking. Updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place that make sense to dispose `httpConfiguration` in owin app, is in `OnAppDisposing`

```
HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);


AppProperties properties = new AppProperties(app.Properties);
CancellationToken token = properties.OnAppDisposing;
if (token != CancellationToken.None)
{
    token.Register(() =>
    {
        httpConfiguration.Dispose();
    });
}
```